# How do you limit per_page results and display pagination links for custom WP REST API endpoint?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have set up a custom WP REST API route and I need help limiting the results to 5 per page and then having pagination links to show the next page etc.

I have tried adding `'per_page => 5'` in the array of arguments, but nothing changes in the results of the url.  I also can't seem to figure out how to include the pagination at all.  Sorry, this is my first go with this.

```
function staffSearchEndpoint(){
    register_rest_route('staffbio/v1', 'staffsearch', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'staffSearchJSONResults',
    ));
}

function staffSearchJSONResults($data) {
    $staffBio = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'staff_bios',
        's' => $data['term'],
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc'
    ));
```

If you can please let me know what to add in the `$staffBio array` or anything else that would be greatly appreciated. Also if Javascript is needed for your answer, please only use plain JS, no JQuery please.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the wrong argument to the WP Query for the post per page. You need to use `'posts_per_page' => 5,` instead of  `'per_page => 5'` in a `WP_Query` argument.

So your `staffSearchJSONResults` function will be:

```
function staffSearchJSONResults($data) {
$staffBio = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'staff_bios',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    's' => $data['term'],
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc'
));
```

For pagination i would suggest to use the `offset` argument.

Let say you have total number of posts in `staff_bios` and the value of `posts_per_page` and say default `offset` value will be 0

So basic logical representation for pagination will be:

```
$pagination_number = 1; //Default pagination number, change as per pagination number
$total_posts = 30;
$posts_per_page = 5;
//This will change based on pagination number, it indicate how many post to skip
$offset = ($pagination_number - 1) * $posts_per_page;  

$data = WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'staff_bios',
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
's' => $data['term'],
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'asc',
'offset' => $offset,
));

$total_pagination = $total_posts/$posts_per_page; //(1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5, ....)

//LOOP THGOUGH DATA
```

You can check all WP_Query argument over here: https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: Momin, thank you for the answer, sorry for the delayed response. I added `'posts_per_page' => 5,` line to my query and that worked great.  However, I am not sure how to set up the pagination markup.  I have never actually done that before, can you tell me how to add those links at the bottom of the results on the frontend?

Comment: Tank you @senior_WordPress_Developer, your solution is for wp_posts (and related table); But what about getting paginated data from custom tables in custom rest endpoints?